# Remove a const qualifier from a variable in D

Tags: metaprogramming, d

I want to create a non-const copy of a variable.  I am doing this inside a templated function, which has an `in ref` input, so the type (`T`) has the const set.  I see a `ConstOf` function in https://dlang.org/phobos/std_traits.html but I cannot find an inverse so I can get a non-const type from `T`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be interested in
[`std.traits.Unqual`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_traits.html#Unqual).

Note that this gives the type with *all* qualifiers removed, not just `const`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove all type qualifiers from a variable you can simply do `cast() variable` which will result in just the base type without any const/immutable/etc.

However beware that this will result in **undefined behaviour** and should be avoided!

See also: https://dlang.org/spec/const3.html#removing_with_cast